# No Json formatter found for type Seq[models.Comment] Try to implement an implicit Format for this type

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

Hello scala and playFramework gurus,

I don't understand why usage of implicit `Json.format[Comment]` does not work in my code. From the docs description it should works as `Format[Comment]` but looks like it doesn't.

Here is code of my two case classes with their companions

```
case class ServiceTask(id: Option[String],
                       name: String,
                       description: String,
                       requiredInfo: String,
                       status: String,
                       approved: Boolean,
                       comments: Option[Seq[Comment]])
object ServiceTask {

  implicit val serviceTaskFormat: Format[ServiceTask] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").formatNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "name").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "description").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "requiredInfo").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "status").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "approved").format[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "comments").formatNullable[Seq[Comment]]
  )(ServiceTask.apply _, unlift(ServiceTask.unapply))

}
```

And

```
  case class Comment(id: Option[String],
                     authorID: BSONObjectID,
                     updatedAt: Option[DateTime] = None,
                     body: String)

  object Comment {
    implicit val commentFormat = Json.format[Comment]
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you didn't import your `commentFormat` in `object serviceTaskFormat`. Try this:

```
object ServiceTask {
  import Comment._

  implicit val serviceTaskFormat: Format[ServiceTask] = (
    (JsPath \ "id").formatNullable[String] and
    (JsPath \ "name").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "description").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "requiredInfo").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "status").format[String] and
    (JsPath \ "approved").format[Boolean] and
    (JsPath \ "comments").formatNullable[Seq[Comment]]
  )(ServiceTask.apply _, unlift(ServiceTask.unapply))
}
```

Comment: Right. In `ServiceTask` my `Comment` implicit Format was invisible before. Thanks

Comment: Also just as a reminder, when there are multiple inner case class in your primary case class, the json `Format` for the inner case classes needs to be defined before, defining json `Format` for the primary case class.

Comment: Thank you, had to do this ; (JsPath \ "id").formatNullable[Long]